# Do we have any pallet or concept for participation key/ Derived Key in Substrate

Tags: pallet

Do we have anything in the substrate to add the participation key/ Derived Key feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that ["participation key"](https://www.purestake.com/blog/participation-keys-in-algorand/) refers to what is available in Algorand to enable keys which can only vote.

In this case, yes, Substrate provides a [Proxy Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/proxy) which allows you to generate [Proxy Accounts](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies) with varying levels of permissions.

This allows one account to act as a proxy to control another account, and submit transactions on their behalf.

We have proxy levels which give the user full access to do everything, and reduced level proxies like for Governance only calls. As a Governance proxy, I would only be able to submit transactions which involve voting or participating in governance, and I would be blocked from doing things like transfers on behalf of the main account.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

- https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/master/pallet_utility/index.html#for-pseudonymal-dispatch

If so, there is some discussion on this here:

- https://www.parity.io/blog/building-a-hot-wallet-with-substrate-primitives/